# Sporadic issue in my application with unknown error codes

Tags: android

I am getting below sporadic error on Android monitor while working on my application.Application will close post logging this message.

> Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 4 in tid 13746 (Chrome_InProcRe)

Can anyone help me on this. Also is there any reference where I can understand the code values mentioned in the error.

Comment: Please help me find  where I can find the references to the error codes.Answer don't have to be specific to question

Comment: Now I got a new one. A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2118 (Chrome_IOThread)